# Half pyramid with Flagpole

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build the Half pyramid with Flagpole in Ruby.  I'm very close just missing the flag and I don't know how to complete it.  Your help is appreciated.

Here is my code: (I can build the half pyramid + pole but not the flag)

```
 n = 1      
 while n <= 5   
   puts ("# " * n).rjust(10) + " |"  
   n += 1  
 end
```

It prints :
        [Half pyramid, missing flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InOcm.png)

this is the desire result :

```
        # |>
      # # |
    # # # |
  # # # # |
# # # # # |
```

Comment: i don't get your problem, can you show us the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use [rosetta](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning) to set the position of the caret in the console and add text (your flagpole).
A second approach is to enhance the existing code with some `if`. I would use `rosetta` for more advanced solutions.

here the if example:

```
n = 1 
while n <= 5 
    if (n == 1)
        puts ("# " * n).rjust(10) + " |>"
    else
        puts ("# " * n).rjust(10) + " |"
    end
    n += 1 
end
```

Comment: @ChantalJustamond : What does a pyramid like in Mario Bros look like? This answer outputs the exact same result as your "desired output".

Comment: thank you @KevinWallis this worked perfectly. I was working on an if /else statement but it wasn't quite right. I will take a look on this rosetta thing. I haven't seen this yet. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[`Kernel#format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) makes it a bit easier :

```
puts format('%18s',  'o')
puts format('%18s', '<|')
puts format('%18s',  '|')

8.times do |i|
  puts format('%9s%9s',
              '#' * (i + 2),
              i == 7 ? '#' : '|')
end
```

It outputs :

```
                 o
                <|
                 |
       ##        |
      ###        |
     ####        |
    #####        |
   ######        |
  #######        |
 ########        |
#########        #
```

Which, as far as I can tell, should be like this picture when used with a square font : [image]

Comment: wow. this another approach. I haven't seen this kernel format but I guess I should take a look at it.